# when sending strings via put extra the underline under some words has gone

Tags: android, textview, underline

when I send strings via put extra the underlined words will not be underlined

```
<string name="s_hello_txt">\n{ <u>hello all</u> }\n</string>
```

MainActivity Button Code

```
public void c_hello(View v){
    Intent hello= new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            MainTextActivity.class);
    intent_collection_e3tiraf.putExtra("key",getResources().getString(R.string.s_hello_txt));
    startActivity(hello);
    finish();
}
```

MainActivityText onCreate Code

```
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_text_txt);
    Intent n = getIntent();
    String mrng = n.getStringExtra("key");
    textview.setText(mrng);
```

if I put a text with direct string it will be underlined

For Example if I put in the layout of MainActivityText(activity_maintext.xml)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_dailyprayers_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/s_hello_txt"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

the textview in MainActivityText Show the text(hello all) underlined

any help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the string still has the underline html you should be able to utilize the [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) method to style the string.

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(mrng));
```

Comment: hey man it's not working when I put your code instead of my code all the style that I've made has gone there is no new lines it's simply all my text has been one continuous text

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the string `getResource().getString(R.string.s_hello_txt)` is not be underlined.
The best way to add html source code in strings.xml is to use `<![CDATA[html source code]]>`. Here is an example:

```
<string name="s_hello_txt"><![CDATA[<u>Text</u>]]></string>
```

And then use `Html.fromHtml(mrng)` to show the underlined string

Comment: man it works fine thank you but there is another problem now with this html
in my strings I used \n to go to a newline but when I use the html there is no new lines

Comment: `<![CDATA[<br/><u>Text</u><br/>]]>`

Comment: it doesn't work
if I have this string file how to change it to work with html
<string name="s_hello_txt">\nhello all\n\n how are you today\n\neverything is fine\n</string>

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try This One This Will Help For Your Acheivement
**String.xml**
 <string name="s_hello_txt">&lt;br/>{ &lt;u>hello all&lt;/u> }&lt;br/></string>

**activity_main1.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/txtValue"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/s_hello_txt"/>

   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/btnClick"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="GoTo Second Activity"/>

</LinearLayout>

**MainActivity1 Activity**
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

    private Button btnClick;
    private TextView txtValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        txtValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtValue);
        btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

        txtValue.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.s_hello_txt)));
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA",getString(R.string.s_hello_txt));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}

**activity_main2.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

**MainActivity2 Activity**
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    private TextView txtValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        txtValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtValue);

        txtValue.setText(Html.fromHtml(getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA")));

    }

}
```